# Get Route Attribute during OWIN Authentication?

Tags: c#, web-services, http, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am first time building a RESTful Webservice with Web Api 2.0 and OWIN middleware, which uses a Token Authentification with Refresh Tokens.
This blog helped me a great deal with that:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

During the Authentication I need an value that specifies to which DB it should connect.
This I can do with `string dbid = context.Parameters.Get("dbid");` ,which gets the value from the request body.

Now my initial plan was to specify that over attribute routing like in the Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/{dbid:length(2)}")]
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/dbid/Customers/id
    // GET: api/XX/Customers/5
    [Authorize]
    [Route("Customer/{id}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Customers))]
    public Customers GetCustomer(string dbid, string id)
    {
        Customers c = null;
        Connection cn = new Connection(dbid);
```

Is this also possible to do that with the TokenEndpointPath?
Like setting `TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/{dbid:length(2)}/token"),` and than somehow accessing the route attribute, extracting the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access route parameters like that in authentication because authentication middleware is before WebApi middleware and also route parameters is a term in WebApi so you can't have it on authentication.

However you can parse request uri and get it yourself if `dbid` is always in same segment of url or if it's in query string.